# Why is the FILES array returning an upload error 3

Tags: php, ubuntu

I had a problem putting together a new server where all of a sudden I was getting upload error 3 on FILES.
Files only partially uploading. Also imagemagik images were coming out distorted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be modsecurity3
I disabled it and it now works.
I did a tail -f modseclog
It is violating rules 200002 and 400000